# How to take a part of current page url

Tags: javascript, html

My page url like is just like that
http://wallpapers.wapego.net/main.php?ses=SuNpnTR5PRYTkYXYN3syARtUHN7&f=3153038
now i want to take a part of current url that is 3153038 and store it into javascript variable

Answer (score 0):

Since you give us no information other than this one URL, you can do it very naively by simply:

```
> var uri = 'http://wallpapers.wapego.net/main.php?ses=SuNpnTR5PRYTkYXYN3syARtUHN7&f=3153038'
< undefined
> var foo = uri.split('&f=')[1]
< undefined
> foo
< "3153038"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to get part of your current url.

```
var currentUrl = location.href;
var urlPart = currentUrl.substring((currentUrl.lastIndexOf("="))+1);
```